# Discontinuous linear operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Does there exists a discontinuous linear operator $T$ between Hausdorff locally convex spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that $T$ is continuous with respect to the weak topologies on $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: The answer is no when $X$ and $Y$ are normed. I'll try to look into it later.

Comment: @Martin Argerami But if they are not normed,  an arbitrary locally convex space?